# how to use view ticker in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Does anyone explain me how I can use  Views Ticker.I loaded modul but no idea how I should use it.please explain me step by step ,I am new on drupal 
thank you.I wanna do somethink like this link 
[enter link description here](http://viewsticker.inettity.com/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a "content type" and name it anything in my own case I will name it "news"

   - To create a content type, navigate to administration->structure->Content type-> add content type
2. You can add new fields to the content type if you wish. But in my own case I will just use the default settings, since I need only the titles to appear as flash news headlines so click "save"
3. Next create a new view and name it anything in my own case I will call it "headlines"

   - To create a new view navigate to administration->structure->views->add new view,
4. Now setup the new view with the following attribiutes; {View Name = headlines, show = content, of type = news, sort by = Newest First, create a page = uncheck, display format = Views Ticker, of = Titles (Linked)", use a pager = unchecked, create a block = checked} now click save and exit
5. Next navigate to Blocks and enable the block we just created through the views. Check for the block name "headlines" and specify the location where you will like to place the newly added block and save.

   - To enable the block navigate to Administration->Structure->Blocks
6. Now Navigate to view and select the new view we just added. In my own case it is called "headlines" and make sure "Format" is set to View Ticker, you can customize the settings of the View Tick by click settings.
7. Next add a news content type using the content type we just created. Add a title, a summary and a content. Then hit save

   - To add a news content type, navigate to Add content

Tip: Add at least two news contents in other to see the full effect of the view ticker

Comment: So I'm using the module. Why can't I edit the CSS properly for the block the module created?  If I define the width of the #block in css this happens:http://postimg.org/image/xnh6zj01r/ (content out ) If I do not define width this happens http://postimg.org/image/v4u0vye43/. Is there a width variable in Views?

Answer (score 0):

There is "Some" documentation in the readme file. check it out and see if it fits your requirements, http://drupalcode.org/project/views_ticker.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.txt

From first glance it seems like a views plugin so you could probably try changing the dispaly in the views settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a new View that pulls in some kind of content (i.e. Announcements).  Under the "Display Format" when creating the View, you'll see an option of "Views Ticker", if you've installed the module correctly. 
Based on the example you pointed to, you'll probably want to create a Block at the same time, that you can insert into the desired region.
Once you've created the View, you'll see a link for the Display Format "Settings".  This is where you choose whether to make it scroll horizontally, vertically, speed, etc.
Once you updated and saved the view, you should go Admin > Structure > Blocks and insert your newly-made Views Ticker block into one of the regions (regions available will vary based on your Theme).
Then, as long as your permissions are correct, and you have actual content,you should see the scrolling ticker show up on the page(s) where the block shows up.

Answer (score 0):

To use views ticker, it needs you to have an view which outputs some data.

I assume you have such a view. Then go to that view's edit page and set format to views ticker. You should have enabled views ticker module to get that option to formats list.

Then it will show you the settings window, in which you can set settings such as vertically, horizontally, BBC, etc styles for your data movement and respective speed etc.

After you did, click on apply button and then save button top of the view's edit page.

If all goes well it should display moving contents in the page/block related to that view.